# enum backward compatibility

Tags: c#, .net

I have enum A which became two enums in version 2 enum B and C.
There is a function GetSpecificEnum() which returns enum A for version 1 and should return enum B and C for version 2 and above. Function itself doing some calculations and returns enum which meets my scenario.

My problem is to properly define this function which can return two versions.
I can always create two functions and somehow get calculations as private refactored method but i'm trying to avoid this.

Is there a way to do it ?

```
public ?? GetSpecificEnum()
{
if(version == 1)
{
//do some stuff
return A.SomeValue;
}
else
{
// do some stuff
return KeyValuePair<B, C>(B.SomeValue, C.SomeValue);
}
}
```

Comment: could you show GetSpecificEnum() function code?

Comment: Would have been easier if this method returned int. Speaking of backward compatibility, what does method returns now?
Edit: Never mind just reread.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the system type `Enum` as the return value for `GetSpecificEnum`. Your code will then have to check the type for the return, and handle it accordingly.

```
    public enum A
    {
        ONE,TWO
    };

    public enum B
    {
        THREE,
        FOUR
    };

    public Enum GetThing(int version)
    {
        return version == 1 ? (Enum)A.ONE : B.THREE;
    }

    public void DoThing()
    {
        Enum e = GetThing(1);
        if (e is A)
        {
            // handle A
            A _a = (A)e;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle B
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would also recommend a generic version `public T GetThing<T>(int version) where T : struct` . Just to save the boxing/unboxing of the result

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz I think his problem is that the calling function doesn't know what the expected enum type should be for the result. So how could it set `T`?

Comment: Mathew, how do i return Enum type i need when DoThing() is void ?

Comment: But he'll have to cast it eventually. well, if that would be somewhere else - then you're right.

Comment: @eugeneK `GetThing` or (in your version) `GetSpecificEnum` is the one which returns the enum

Comment: @eugeneK DoThing is the handler. It's an example of how the business logic would handle backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you are an API/product provider:

```
    public enum OldEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    public enum NewPart1
    {
        One,
        Two
    }

    public enum NewPart2
    {
        Three
    }

[Obsolete("This method is intended to by used be previous versions")]
    public OldEnum GetEnum(someparameters here)
    {

        // Some processing here
        return OldEnum.One;
    }

    public NewPart1 GetEnum(someparameters here)
    {
        // Do something here
        return NewPart1.One;
    }

    public NewPart2 GetEnum(someparameters here)
    {
        // Do something here
        return NewPart2.Three;
    }
```

If your enumerations are split of old enumeration, you do not really need to make change to code. In the end, we are dealing with integers. Please note, split enumerations still retain same integer values as earlier. You can then just cast the integer value and send it across.